# Call to undefined function handler

Tags: php, php-5.3

Is it possible to handle this type of errors? Something like spl_autoload_register, but for functions.

Basically, what I am trying to do:

I have the class:

```
class Foo {
   public function bar() {
     echo 1;
   } 
}
```

So, when I call a nonexistent function Foo() like this:

```
Foo()->bar();
```

The possible handler should create a function Foo(), which looks like that:

```
function Foo() {
   return new Foo();
}
```

Comment: interesting question. Does it have to be a function like that? Do you have any special reason to want to do this? I can't think of any method to "auto-load" functions, but maybe there's another way to achieve your goal?

Comment: No, this is not possible: autoloading is for classes only. What's the problem with just doing `$foo = new Foo; $foo->bar();`?

Comment: There reason is just to write less code :)

For example, I have this code:

$friends = new FriendsModel();
$this->friends = $friends->getUserFriends($userId);

I don't use $friends object anywhere else, so it would be useful to have something like this:
$this->friends = FriendsModel()->getUserFriends($userId);

I can create a function FriendsModel(), but it seems to be redundant when you have many classes like this, so I wanted to optimize the process.

Comment: Don't worry, a number of us others hate PHP for not supporting `new Foo()->bar();` too.

Comment: @BoltClick, while having a Fluid interface for `new` would be nice you would hope in your example `bar()` returned `$this`.  Becareful what you wish for in a language because you'll have to maintain it.

Comment: It would also be a significant performance hit to use an error handler to attempt to guess the programmers intention. Any reason static methods can't handle your particular case?

Comment: @Yzmir Ramirez: What? Why does it *have* to? Not everything in a fluid interface has to return the working instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you never need an actual instance of the object, why not use a static class?

```
class Foo {
   public static function bar() {
     echo 1;
   } 
}

Foo::bar();
```

Then, you can do this in your app:

```
$this->fiends = FriendsModel::getUserFriends($userId);
```